# 959 ошибка при импорте БД

Tags: sql, oracle

Команда:

```
C:\oraclex64\product\12.1.0\client\BIN\imp.exe PARFILE=IMP_PAR.par

====

USERID=USER_2/PASSWORD_2@DB
FROMUSER=USER_1
TOUSER=USER_2
FILE=DMPFILE.DMP
LOG=DMPFILE.log 
STATISTICS=NONE
CONSTRAINTS=Y
```

Скопировались многие таблицы, но многие выругались таким:

```
. . importing table                    "RUN_STATS"          0 rows imported
. . importing table               "SCRIPTS_BEFORE"          0 rows imported
IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 959:
 "CREATE TABLE "SOME_TABLE" ("SCPT_ID" NUMBER(7, 0) NOT NULL ENABLE, "
 ""TEXT" CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE)  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INIT"
 "RANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 TABLESPACE "USERS" LOGGING NOCOMPRESS LOB ("TEXT") STOR"
 "E AS BASICFILE  (TABLESPACE "T_SPACE_D" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192"
 " RETENTION  NOCACHE LOGGING )"
IMP-00003: ORACLE error 959 encountered
ORA-00959: tablespace 'T_SPACE_D' does not exist
```

То есть, судя по всему какие-то таблицы созданы в пространстве, которое отстутствует в целевой База Данных. Как быть? ._.

p.s. Видел похожий вопрос в англоязычном stackoverflow, но не осилил. Datapump какой-то советуют. Как им пользоваться - не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта решения:

1. создать табличные пространства с такими же именами в целевой БД
2. переназначить табличные пространства воспользовавшись [параметром `impdp` - `REMAP_TABLESPACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-F467946E-50B3-4CC0-937A-CC8C18AAF8C1):

   ```
   REMAP_TABLESPACE=(OLD_TS_NAME1:NEW_TS_NAME1,OLD_TS_NAME2:NEW_TS_NAME2)
   ```

Чтобы выяснить какие TABLESPACE используются в DUMP файле можно создать SQL со всеми DDL statements:

```
impdp user/password directory=dir_name dumpfile=DMPFILE.DMP sqlfile=ddls.sql
```

после можно найти все TABLESPACE:

```
grep -i TABLESPACE ddls.sql
```

Comment: REMAP_TABLESPACE - не известный параметр для imp.exe. Видимо, тут речь именно про этот data pump - impdp. Но не вкурю как им пользоваться ._.

Comment: @ВиталийЯндулов, да, я имел ввиду DATA PUMP. У вас dumpfile чем был подготовлен - `exp` или `expdp`?

Comment: Через exp, про expdp я только сегодня услышал ._.

Comment: Тогда вам, похоже, только первый вариант остается...

Comment: Я попробовал ворваться в файл дампа текстовым редактором и зареплейсить все пространства имен. Как ни странно, получилось меньше ошибок, но была ошибка 1917 -.-

Comment: В целом, база то под рукой, можно было бы попытаться сделать дамп и expdp

Comment: С `expdp` - будет гораздо меньше проблем, но есть одно "но" - файл  дампа можно будет использовать только локально на сревере целевой БД или через DB link...